# Will we be able to toggle visibility of our CVs on careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

My reasoning goes as follows:

"Wow $29 for 3 years, that's a good deal, I'll buy it now!"

"Hang on, I like my job, I don't want to change right now"

Would it be possible to turn your CV on and off? Or at least have some kind of slider which goes between "Don't call me" and "Get me outta here"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible; this option appears in the dashboard once you have filed:

### Your CV is searchable by employers; [hide from searches](http://example.com/)

Comment: Is that link *supposed* to point to "example.com"?

Comment: I think it is pointing to a dummy URL because he is showing that once you have filed, you will see a message like that, with a link to hide your CV. Where the link points to would be different for every person (ie, it would have different parameters), and it wouldn't be appropriate for people to click it from here.