# How temporary is the CV temporary access link on careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

In addition to simply [toggling public CV visibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25059), the CV publish page also has a feature allowing a user to "share your CV using this temporary access link" where "access link" is a hyperlink to a page that shows the CV by routing to it with some sort of hash in the url like this:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/view/<some-sort-of-hash-here>
```

So the options are:

- Publish the CV publicly
- Do not publish the CV publicly
- Sort of publish the CV publicly with this temporary link

I think the third option is cool. I could imagine somebody not wanting to publish a CV to the world at large, but wanting to send it to some prospective employer that is not subscribed to the employer search.

My question is this: **how long is the temporary access link active?** Or maybe the question should be **how do I deactivate a temporary access link?** Or perhaps even **do I only get one temporary access link?** (I've clicked on it a few times and the hash is always the same).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think the third option is cool. I could image somebody not wanting to publish a CV to the world at large, but wanting to send it to some prospective employer that is not subscribed to the employer search.

Yes, that is exactly what it is for.

If you mouseover the link, the tooltip will tell you the duration it is good for.

(The links are valid for 4 days.)

Comment: Ah! The mouseover! I totally missed that - thanks! Does it decrement day-by-day so that tomorrow it will say something like "valid for 3 days," etc.?

Comment: @Greg: most likely you will get a new link after the old link has been "activated", which lasts 4 days as well